# Share Session with WKWebView

Tags: wkwebview

I have an app that uses AFNetworking to log the user in to a web service. I want to load a WKWebView using the same session as that one being stored in the AFNetworking GET/POSTS to my webservice but google has failed me so far. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

I can no doubt get the session id from AFNetworking and manually pass it to my NSURLRequest for my WKWebView, but that seems a bit too manual, or is that the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance!